# Can ServiceStack validate JWT OOTB

Tags: authentication, servicestack, jwt

I'm looking over the auth docs
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization

Basically what I would LOOOVE to do is simplify our service auth.  Basically say "If this is being run in the context of an authenticated CMS user (in the API) use that person, if user is ANON, check for a JWT in the header, and run in the context of that user"

So I assume this would all be some sort of custom attribute? (I mean ideally I'd like an attribute or something).  Right now we just have a method that lives at the top of every call to do this validation... would love to abstract it all out if possible somehow.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Steve

Comment: Note - JWT Auth is now possible with ServiceStack since version 4.0.58 :) see release notes: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/docs/2016/v4.0.58.md#jwt-auth-provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not included in the framework itself however there are a couple of external projects that enable token-based authentication with ServiceStack:

- [StatelessAuthentication](https://github.com/rvhelden/StatelessAuthentication)
- [Using IdentityServer 4 with ServiceStack and Angular](http://estynedwards.com/blog/2016/01/30/ServiceStack-IdentityServer-Angular/)
- [Auth0 ServiceStack Integration](https://auth0.com/docs/server-platforms/servicestack)
- [ServiceStack JWT Token validation for Auth0](https://gist.github.com/svantreeck/436f6ddddda38c735c62)

Comment: Fantastic, needed it for Auth0 anyway :D